# lambda expression as parameter

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I want to access an object through a method that takes a lambda expression and the class instance as parameters.This is what I have tried

```
public static string Tester(Func<string, string> param = (a) => string.Format("Name:{0}", a), Dog toDisplay)
{
    return param;
}
```

But it is clear that i cant have func<> as a parameter.
at the end i want to be able to  access and display data as shown below.

```
string a = Program.Tester(walter => walter.GetDetails(),dog);
```

How can I go about with the  parameter?

Comment: This is not C code.

Comment: then what is it?this is what i coded???

Comment: Really? You don't know what language you are coding in?? Looks like C# to me.

Comment: C and C# are two different languages — very different languages; they're even more different from each other than C and C++, but those too are very different languages.  To prosper on Stack Overflow, you do need to understand which language you're programming in.  Incorrect tagging will lead to many down-votes.

Comment: Correct me if im wrong but i used a C# tag. I thought i used a the correct tag,its my firrst time asking a question. can you help?

Comment: I have edited the question and added C# and .NET tags because the code looks like C# code (because of Func<> delegate). Feel free to edit tags and set values you want.

Comment: Johnmate - also take 2 minutes of your time and complete the site [tour].

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Delegate` (`Action<T>`)

- Delegate: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459(v=vs.71).aspx
- Or here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx